# Is there any free English education in Canada for foreigners?

Tags: canada, study, english-language

I'm planning a trip to Vancouver and all the English Learning schools seem to charge something around $200 a week. I'm running out of options because my money is limited, so I heard a few days ago that Canada has institutions that provide free English education.

- Do they really exist?
- How they work?
- Can I apply as a foreigner?

Comment: I suppose online education tools (like http://livemocha.com/), that are available in Canada are out of scope, right?

Comment: why do you want to learn English while you're in Canada? Are you just visiting as a tourist for a few weeks and want to pick up some language skills, or is this the point of the trip? I get the feeling some of those schools charge those fees because they are used as a reason for visiting by people who want to meet Canadians and lay the groundwork for returning later as an immigrant. If you only want the language teaching part of the deal, you can get it for a lot less.

Comment: @KateGregory , I want to improve my English skills. Like, grammar and stuff. Are there cheaper schools?

Comment: But is improving your skills the reason for the trip, or just something you want to take advantage during a vacation? And how long is the trip?

Comment: Yes, it's the main reason of the trip. This is actually for a friend of mine, you can notice it by my writing skills. He has enough money for accomodation and food for 6 months, but the schools are too expensive. His family is very poor and I want to help him to get the best school options.

Comment: I heard about free English teaching schools, although price is the main reason I've posted this question, you should consider that **I'm interest about this type of education either**.

Comment: If your friend has enough money for food and accommodation for six months, and really wants to learn English, then the best way is to enrol in a 3 month language course. Spend the money he would have spent on the extra three months of living expenses on a good school.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes there really are institutions that provide free English (and French) language classes, funded by the Canadian government.

Unforunately for you they are intended to improve the language skills of Canadians, especially new Canadians. They are restricted to permanent residents of Canada.

See here for [information about government funded language courses](http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/newcomers/after-education-language.asp).

Comment: Depending on OPs nationality he might get away with claiming himself as a refugee and then enjoying the free course...

Comment: @JonathanReez Applying for refugee status would be a bit more serious than "a trip".